# Resolver erro SVN: "must be ancestrally related to..."

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Com o TortoiseSVN criei uma *branch* para produção a partir do meu *trunk*, só que depois de um tempo quando tento fazer o ***merge*** do *trunk* na *producao* dá o seguinte erro:

> 'http://hostname/repositorio/trunk@50' must be ancestrally related to 'http://hostname/repositorio/branches/producao@43'

Por que isso acontece e como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

O *branch* foi criado manualmente ou usando a opção "TortoiseSVN -> Branch/tag"? Uma possível solução imediata pode ser usar `svn merge --ignore-ancestry`.

Perguntas relacionadas no *stackoverflow* em inglês:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/490164/1814415
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/22204268/1814415

Comment: Criei manualmente usando a opção que você descreveu e também marquei a opção **ignore-ancestry** mas dá outro erro: "Cannot merge automatically while ignoring mergeinfo"

Comment: Isso parece ocorrer por causa de informações expúrias no svn:mergeinfo, essa resposta no stackoverflow em inglês pode ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2648969/1814415

Comment: Seu problema foi resolvido ?